# How can I associate values in a table with ranges in another table?

Tags: sql, range, sas

Consider the following simple two table setup:

```
drop table ranges;
drop table entries;

create table ranges (x integer, y integer, label varchar);
create table entries (v integer);

insert into ranges values(1, 5, "range1");
insert into ranges values(8, 10, "range2");
insert into ranges values(20, 30, "range3");

insert into entries values(0);
insert into entries values(3);
insert into entries values(8);
insert into entries values(12);
insert into entries values(23);
```

Now, the query

```
select * from entries as a, ranges as b
where a.v between b.x and b.y;
```

will give me

```
v|x|y|label
3|1|5|range1
8|8|10|range2
23|20|30|range3
```

That is, values in `entries` which do not fall into any of the ranges will not appear in the results.

How can I write a query that will return a row for each entry in `entries` so that I get

```
v|x|y|label
0|NULL|NULL|NULL
3|1|5|range1
8|8|10|range2
12|NULL|NULL|NULL
23|20|30|range3
```

preferably in generic SQL (I am using `PROC SQL` in SAS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * 
from entries as a
left outer join ranges as b 
  on (a.v between b.x and b.y);
```

And a +1 from me for providing sensible and usable DDL and INSERT statements. It's a pleasure to help you.

Comment: Thank you for helping me get my mind unstuck. I don't know why but I was going through a bunch of contortions, forgetting about `outer join`.